how to plot multiple linear regression features vs predicted results on individual graphs
I was working on a TV advertisement dataset with 3 features (TV, radio, newspaper) and 1 dependent variable (sales). By using multiple linear regression, I estimated sales and compared them with actual values on my y_test dataset. I already confirmed that my model achieved high r2 score.
I am aware of the fact that in multiple linear regression, multiple features can be visualized on higher dimension plots. However, I would like to see each individual feature vs. predicted results on separated graphs.
import pandas
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import dataset and assign to X and y
df = pandas.read_csv("Advertising.csv")
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values

#split the dataset into X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

#initialize regressor and train it with X_train and y_train
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predict the test results and plot them with actual values
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print("predicted values/actual values")
print(numpy.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred), 1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test), 1)), axis=1))

#evaluate model performance for prediction results
r_squared_linear = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(f"multiple linear regression model performance is {r_squared_linear}")

#see OLS regression results
mod = sm.OLS(y.reshape(-1, 1), X)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())

#plot each feature of the dataset vs predicted results on individual graphs

This is my code and it works without any issues. I just want to complete the plotting section with matplotlib. I want to plot each individual feature (TV, radio, newspaper) vs. y_pred values that my model has predicted, including the linear regression line on each plot.
I'll appreciate a lot if anyone can show me how to do it with a for loop (to make sure it will work with any feature count on different datasets).
Also, for extra knowledge, how can I plot all features in the same plot with y_pred results as well?
